# How to ensure an xml entity has a valid name

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-validation

I have an app that generates a bunch of xml based off of some data from a source that I don't control. Basically I'm turning that data into an xml doc for serving via rss feeds. I may be getting data like

```
2_br=1
3_br=0
```

and I'm turning it into the following xml

```
<2_br>1</2_br>
<3_br>0</3_br>
```

Obviously an xml tag can't start with a digit. I couldn't find anywhere a list of valid characters. Does it exists somewhere? I'm basically just going to prefix and invalid starting character or replace an inline invalid character with an `_`.

It's not hard to do, but basically I just cant find a list of invalid characters for an xml tag name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:[Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-S)

***NameStartChar***    ::=      ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]

Comment: How strange and dangerous... the ":" character is technically valid as a name character.  I never knew that.

Comment: ":" is allowed because namespaces weren't yet introduced when XML recommendation was finished. Therefore an XML document that has an element with a name that contains multiple ":" characters can be *well formed and valid* but it won't be *namespace well formed* because it doesn't conform to XML namespaces recommendation. As a result an XML parser might reject such document because (in addition to well-formedness) the parser can require namespace conformance.

Comment: Also note that the list of allowed name characters was different in 4th edition of the XML 1.0 recommendation, disallowing some currently allowed characters. Some older parsers *might* conform only to 4th edition (or older) and might reject documents that are valid per 5th edition. Current character list of XML 1.0 matches the XML 1.1 recommendation.

Comment: Please also note that you can't use that name production rule as is in a .NET regular expression. .NET strings are encoded using UTF-16 and `U+10000` is greater than 16-bits. The proper way to encode the last character class shown above is to use UTF-16 surrogate pairs that enocde characters in the range shown into 2 16-bit values. You should use the following regex representation in .NET: `([\uD800-\uDB7F][\uDC00-\uDFFF])`. This pattern will match all UTF characters between `U+10000` and `U+EFFFF`.

Comment: .Net and java Strings arent encoded they hold raw characters that happen to be 16 bits wide or 10000(hex).

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlConvert.IsNCNameChar()
```

and

```
XmlConvert.IsStartNCNameChar()
```

can be used to validate a XML-tag name:

```
char[] validTagNameChars = pDesiredTagName.Where(ch => XmlConvert.IsNCNameChar(ch)).ToArray();
string validTagName = new string (validTagNameChars);
if (validTagName == "" || !XmlConvert.IsStartNCNameChar(validTagName[0]))
  validTagName = "_" + validTagName;
```