# Why is my regex failing?

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying create a regex that verifies an xml entity name is valid (see related issue: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617212/how-to-ensure-an-xml-entity-has-a-valid-name/4617309#4617309)).

```
(:|[A-Z]|_|[a-z]|[\xC0-\xD6]|[\xD8-\xF6]|[\xF8-\x2FF]|[\x370-\x37D]|[\x37F-\x1FFF]|[\x200C-\x200D]|[\x2070-\x218F]|[\x2C00-\x2FEF]|[\x3001-\xD7FF]|[\xF900-\xFDCF]|[\xFDF0-\xFFFD]|[\x10000-\xEFFFF])
```

Basically it's verifying that the first character is a valid character. However the token `[\xF8-\x2FF]` is bombing out regex validation. Any idea why? I can't figure it out.

**UPDATE**
The .net parser is throwing an exception that says `range in reverse order.`

Comment: Which regex parser did you use?

Comment: several, but this is the one I most commonly use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Might I recommend [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)?  If you had used that, you would have spotted the problem immediately.

Comment: Just a note, since nobody mentioned it, `:|[A-Z]|_|[a-z]` is the same as `[:A-Z_a-z]` - you can pretty much drop all of these `]|[` and stay with one character class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use one character per range in a regex and most regex parsers don't understand multiple bytes using the `\x` notation.  Use the `\u` notation instead.

```
(:|[A-Z]|_|[a-z]|[\xC0-\xD6]|[\xD8-\xF6]|[\xF8-\u02FF]|[\u0370-\u037D]|[\u037F-\u1FFF]|[\u200C-\u200D]|[\u2070-\u218F]|[\u2C00-\u2FEF]|[\u3001-\uD7FF]|[\uF900-\uFDCF]|[\uFDF0-\uFFFD]|[\u10000-\uEFFFF])
```

[The .NET regex documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e.aspx) states

> `\x20`    Matches an ASCII character using
>   2-digit hexadecimal. In this case,
>   `\x2-` represents a space.

And for unicode:

> `\u0020`  Matches a Unicode character
>   using exactly four hexadecimal digits.
>   In this case `\u0020` is a space.

So I've used both above, `\x` for the 2-char hex values and `\u` for the larger ones.

Comment: Actually, that regex show n above won't work. I tried it, too. :)  The problem is, try an ID such as `i@`. It will pass. But this is not a valid XML ID (or NMTOKEN) token. The problem is with the `[\u10000-\uEFFFF]` in your regex. .NET regex's only accept UTF-16 character sequences, and `U+10000` is greater than 16-bits in length. The character class should be changed to use UTF-16 surrogate pairs as follows: `([\uD800-\uDB7F][\uDC00-\uDFFF])`. This will match all UTF characters in the range `U+10000` through `U+EFFFF`. Now IDs like `i@` will not validate. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Because `\x2F` is one ASCII character.  It is treating `[\xF8-\x2FF]` as a match  between `\xF8-\x2F` (an invalid range) or the character `F`.

Use `\u` for unicode: `[\u00F8-\u02FF]`